# Running SPSS session action from an external Python script

Tags: python, spss

I have a Python 2.7 script that among others contains the following piece of code:

```
import spss    

columns = []

spss.StartDataStep()
dataset = spss.Dataset()
for column in dataset.varlist:
    columns.append(column.name)
spss.EndDataStep()

print columns
```

When running this code inside a SPSS syntax (so between `BEGIN PROGRAM.` and `END PROGRAM`), it runs as expected and I end up with the variables in the active dataset.

However, when running the same code as part of a script (so from `Utilities > Run script...`) will return me no results.

It looks as if the SPSS session context is not taken into consideration when running a script.

Is there a way around this problem, or am I doing something wrong?
I don't want to run my code as part of Syntax file, I just want to use vanilla Python scripts.

Answer (score 2):

This is, unfortunately, a complicated issue.  I don't think Statistics is working as documented.  I will take this up with Development.

It appears that in V24, when you run a Python script via Utilities > Run Script (which is the same as issuing the SCRIPT command), your script is connected to the Statistics Viewer process but not to the Statistics backend (the spssengine process), which is where the data live.  There are typically three processes running - the stats.exe process, the spssengine process, and, for Python code, the startx process.  Your script can issue commands via the spss.Submit api and can use other spss apis, but they go against a new copy of the backend, so the expected backend context is not present.

To get around this, you can run a trivial program like

```
begin program.  
import ascript  
end program.
```

where ascript.py is a Python module on the Python search path.  (You could put these lines in an sps file and use INSERT to execute it, too.)

Another way to approach this would be to run Statistics in external mode.  In that mode, you run a Python program that uses SPSS apis but the Python program is on top, and no Statistics user interface appears.  You can read about this in the Python scripting help.

An advantage of external mode is that you can use your favorite Python IDE to build and debug your code.  That's a big advantage if you are basically a Python person.  I use Wing IDE, but any Python IDE should work.  You can also set up an alternative IDE as your default by editing the clientscriptingcfg.ini file in the Statistics installation directory.  See the scripting help for details.  With a tool like Wing, this lets you debug your scripts or other Python code even if run within Statistics.

Comment: I have actually tried running in _external mode_, but unfortunately it had died on me. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834241/running-a-python-script-with-spss
For now, I'm just running a syntax file which essentially wraps a bunch of Python classes and functionality. Not easy to look at, but it does the job.

Comment: I don't know why that script failed, but if you display the Python path in internal mode and external mode, you should be able to see what is missing and add that in external mode.